Error Saving TransformerDecoder Model in Keras NLP: TypeError with Non-JSON-Serializable Arguments
I am having an issue saving a TransformerDecoder model from keras_nlp. Could you please advise how I can resolve this?
Here is my code:
from keras_nlp.layers import TransformerDecoder
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Embedding, GlobalAveragePooling1D, Input

decoder_input = Input(shape=(128,), name="decoder_input")
embedding = Embedding(input_dim=10000, output_dim=32, name="embedding")(decoder_input)
decoder = TransformerDecoder(intermediate_dim=64, num_heads=2, name="decoder")(embedding)
pooled = GlobalAveragePooling1D(name="pooling")(decoder)
output = Dense(token_size, activation="softmax", name="output_dense")(pooled)
model = Model(inputs=decoder_input, outputs=output)

model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])

model.save("model.keras")

Error I am getting:
TypeError: Layer tf.__operators__.add was passed non-JSON-serializable arguments. 
Arguments had types: {'y': <class 'keras.src.backend.tensorflow.core.Variable'>, 'name': <class 'NoneType'>}. 
They cannot be serialized out when saving the model.

Version of packages:
print(tensorflow.__version__)
print(keras_nlp.__version__)
# 2.17.0
# 0.14.1


It seems there are a few wrong arguments. activation of Dense, and loss of Model.compile() shall be a function, but you passed a string

try to build the model first, or pass data to the model before saving it. it will instantiate the different layer

@Mike Thanks! It seems like string arguments are valid. activation='signoid' will be converted into tf.keras.activations.signoid() as this post  explained.

@GhassenSultana I actually trained the model and tried to save it, but I did not share the training code to simplify the problem here. Regardless of whether I save before or after the training, I get the same error.

I could not reproduce the error in a collab environment, it did work for me with the specified package version tensorflow 2.17.0 and keras_nlp 0.14.1.


Thanks for your support! hmm... interesting, so this error is coming from something else.. I wonder how I can work around it..

it's certainly from an utility package, try to do the same experience as i did in collab and after that do a pip freeze and compare the two environment, it also can be helpful if you provide all the available traceback of the error
